# Calculo de Médias envolvendo uma coluna e duas linhas

Tags: php, mysql, matemática

Estou finalizando um pequeno sistema de gerenciamento e calculo de notas e estou tendo uma certa dificuldade para realizar o calculo de médias.

[imagem do banco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXxen.png)

Preciso calcular a média de cada matéria no período, observe, existe uma coluna `nota_período` e a coluna `nota_tipo`, o valor da coluna `nota_período` é **um só**, ja que ele representa **duas notas** e o valor das notas da coluna **nota_tipo** não, ja que é uma coluna que classifica as notas em **Global e Parcial** ou seja, *a nota global é uma nota e a nota parcial é outra nota*, com isso, estou com dificuldades para estabelecer uma lógica para realizar o calculo de soma e média de todas as matérias por período usando PHP.

ate o momento, apos algumas tentativas eu fiz esse trecho de código que não funciona tão bem...

```
$port = array();
$mat = array();

$html = json_encode($port). $port[1][" "];
$html = json_encode($mat). $mat[2][" "];

$tipos = array();
$tipos = array(0 => "parcial", 1 => "global");

for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
        $soma = array_sum($port[$i]);
        $soma = array_sum($mat[$i]);
        $avg = ($soma) / 2;
        $avg = number_format($avg, 1, '.', '');
        $html = $avg;        // variável responsável por imprimir o valor.
        $i++;
    }

    $j++;
}
```

Comment: "esse trecho de código que não funciona tão bem"; mas tem algum erro?

Comment: ele trás a nota das duas matérias, mas só realiza o calculo da média de uma, meio que não sei como fazer ele realizar o calculo das duas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código realmente está usando apenas *uma das matérias* pra cálcuo;

```
...
$soma = array_sum($port[$i]);
$soma = array_sum($mat[$i]);
...
```

A segunda linha está sobrescrevendo o valor de soma, assim ele só considera as notas de `$mat`. Sendo assim, você só precisa que `$soma` receba das duas variáveis:

```
...
$soma = array_sum($port[$i]);
$soma += array_sum($mat[$i]);

//também podes fazer em apenas uma linha
//$soma = array_sum($port[$i]) + array_sum($mat[$i]);
...
```